# Why dataTable return an empty record with no data when using server side processing?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thQFw.png)I need some help here and been stuck close to day and half now, problem is i am not returning any record from my DataTable. What exactly am i  missing?, yes i am calling correct table and has data. Here is my logic below, it has this function to getList and empList does not return any value. Please help mates to resolve this issue, thanks; While debubbing the server side does see some reference with data just its not populating as readable file to the user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQXVo.png)

```
// Model

 public class EventsManagementTb
    {
        public int TrainingID { get; set; }

        public string TrainingType { get; set; }
        public string TrainingDescription { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public string Venue { get; set; }

        public string Facilitator { get; set; }

        public string WhoAttend { get; set; }

        public string RSVP { get; set; }
    }

    // Controller

      [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult GetData()
            {
                //Server side Parameter.
                JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

                try
                {
                    // Initilization
                    string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
                    string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
                    string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
                    string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
                    int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
                    int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);


                    // Loading.
                    List<EventsManagementTb> data = this.LoadData();

                    // Total record count.

                    int totalRecords = data.Count;

                    // Verification.
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                    {
                        // Apply search

                        data = data.Where(l => l.TrainingID.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.TrainingType.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.TrainingDescription.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Price.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Venue.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.Facilitator.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.WhoAttend.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                        || l.RSVP.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
                    }

                    // Sorting
                    data = this.SortByColumnWithOrder(order, orderDir, data);

                    // Filter record data.
                    int recFilter = data.Count;

                    // Apply pagination.

                    data = data.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize).ToList();

                    result = this.Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = recFilter, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                return result;

            }



            private List<EventsManagementTb> SortByColumnWithOrder(string order, string orderDir, List<EventsManagementTb> data)
            {
                // Initialization.
                List<EventsManagementTb> lst = new List<EventsManagementTb>();

                try
                {
                    // Sorting
                    switch (order)
                    {
                        case "0":

                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.TrainingID).ToList()
                                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.TrainingID).ToList();
                            break;

                        case "1":
                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.TrainingType).ToList()
                                        : data.OrderBy(l => l.TrainingType).ToList();
                            break;

                        case "2":
                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.TrainingDescription).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.TrainingDescription).ToList();
                            break;

                        case "3":
                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Price).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.Price).ToList();
                            break;


                        case "4":

                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Venue).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.Venue).ToList();
                            break;

                        case "5":

                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.Facilitator).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.Facilitator).ToList();
                            break;

                        case "6":

                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.WhoAttend).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.WhoAttend).ToList();
                            break;

                        default:
                            lst = orderDir.Equals("DESC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? data.OrderByDescending(l => l.RSVP).ToList()
                                : data.OrderBy(l => l.RSVP).ToList();

                            break;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }


                return lst;
            }



            private List<EventsManagementTb> LoadData()
            {
                List<EventsManagementTb> lst = new List<EventsManagementTb>();

                try
                {
                    string line = string.Empty;
                    string srcFilePath = "content/files/EventsManagementTb.txt";
                    var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
                    string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

                    //Read file

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        EventsManagementTb tb = new EventsManagementTb();
                        string[] info = line.Split(',');

                        // Setting
                        tb.TrainingID = Convert.ToInt32(info[0].ToString());
                        tb.TrainingType = info[1].ToString();
                        tb.TrainingDescription = info[2].ToString();
                        tb.Price = Convert.ToInt32(info[3].ToString());
                        tb.Venue = info[4].ToString();
                        tb.Facilitator = info[5].ToString();
                        tb.WhoAttend = info[6].ToString();
                        tb.RSVP = info[7].ToString();

                        // Adding
                        lst.Add(tb);
                    }
                    sr.Dispose();
                    sr.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }

                return lst;
            }

        }
    // View cshtml
     <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({

                    "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] }, 
                    { "className": "text-center custom-middle-align" ,"targets":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
                    ],
                    "language":{
                        "processing": "<div class = 'overlay custom-loader-background'><i class= 'fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></idv>"
                },
                    "serverSide":"true",
                    "processing":"true",
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype":"json"
                    },
                       "columns": [
                        {"data":"TrainingID"},
                        {"data": "TrainingType"},
                        { "data": "TrainingDescription"},
                        { "data": "Price"},
                        { "data": "Venue"},
                        { "data": "Facilitator"},
                        { "data": "WhoAttend"},
                        {"data": "RSVP"},
                    ]


                });

            });
```

Comment: The result while debugging states "DenyGetAny" on JsonRequestBehavior. What does it mean mates.

Comment: Hi Mates can anyone kindly please help me

Comment: Where do you get this error: `DenyGetAny" on JsonRequestBehavior.` ?

Comment: When  i debug using cursor on my code on the return result

Comment: Can you post the entire error that you get while performing this operation?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet result = this.Json(new{ draw = Convert.Into32(draw), recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = recFilter, data= data}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Decorate your `GetData` method with this: `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]`

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: I did issue is on DataTableId being Invalid Json, maybe my mapping for the columns are incorrect busy relooking them